# How to resend viewstate on Membership / Session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently, when the using is logged in (using the built in forms authentication) and they let their session timeout, they loose all data when they submit a form. How do I make it so that the viewstate data is resubmitted AFTER logging back in? Example, if they were writing an email and it expires, how do I make it send after they relogin instead of loosing all their data? I don't want a solution that extends the session on these pages please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewstate` will only work in postback-scenarios,you will lose it if you redirect.So i think you use `session` for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shree..

You could use a timer of sorts and either do a save to the DB, Session, or Cookie w/ the temp date entered so far.

Also, what I have done on some applications, is before the session will time out give the user a warning popup to "Continue" the session.  This takes a little more work..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the state of the form along with all form data, you don't want automatic redirects to the login page, which means that you need some sort of an "in place" authentication. You may consider intercepting the postback, i.e. adding your own handler to the form submit event, and issuing an AJAX callback to check your session state. If the session is valid, just proceed with the postback, otherwise display a login page in a popup or a modal dialog. The user will be able to resubmit the form after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not on ViewState, simple solution is save the email and action into local storage[HTML5], when user re-logs on, check the previous action and email, then you can submit email automatically. All browsers except IE6/7 already support local storage now.